# Error linking Facebook library with MGTwitterEngine

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to integrate Facebook into my app and have already implemented MGTwitterEngine with no issues. I keep getting an error now that I have tried to implement both Facebook sdk and MGTwitterEngine. I have read that there is a duplicate library between both SDK's and the individual said it had to do with the JSON Libraries. I deleted it from the Facebook sdk but I am still getting the error. Does anyone know what the issue may be?

So I understand it is referring to my armv6 in the error but there is no error at all until I try running Facebook sdk

Thanks

```
Ld "/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Intermediates/grocery.build/Release-iphoneos/grocery.build/Objects-normal/armv6/grocery" normal armv6
cd /Users/Alex/Documents/Dictator/Lotto
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv6 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos "-L/Users/Alex/Documents/Dictator/Lotto/Classes/Twitter+OAuth 2/SAOAuthTwitterEngine" -F/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Intermediates/grocery.build/Release-iphoneos/grocery.build/Objects-normal/armv6/grocery.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=3.1 -framework Security -lxml2 -framework MessageUI -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework MapKit -framework SystemConfiguration -lOAuth -o "/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Intermediates/grocery.build/Release-iphoneos/Lotto Fetcher.build/Objects-normal/armv6/grocery"

ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Intermediates/grocery.build/Release-iphoneos/Lotto Fetcher.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main-280587BD193E8878.o and /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery-bhrkiajnjqfieahhdxilwtjggbqc/Build/Intermediates/grocery.build/Release-iphoneos/Lotto Fetcher.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main-B9843B6026D6EFA4.o for architecture armv6    

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Duplicate symbol
```

Comment: That's not the full error details.  Could you post the full error details?

Comment: Especially what is the actual duplicate symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your project for two copies of main.m file. :-)